# How to delete session data from django_session table when user closes browser

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using Django Session Authentication. I set `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` as i want users to login each time they close the browser. All works fine user closes browser session got deleted from browser but session data is still there in the django_session table having expire_date with 14 days validity. In this case how will i run cron job to delete useless session data ? I wanted to run cron which will identify expired session then delete them but even if session data is useless i cant delete because expire date have 14 days validity.